# PHP Mail file sending but no message body is including

Tags: php, email

I am sending a file to an email address.  The file is sent correctly but the message is not attaching with it. (e.g. Kindly find the attached file).

When I send the email, the file is attached correctly, but there is no message body in it.

```
$name        = $name;
$email       = $email;
$to          = "$name <$email>";
$from        = "Travel Mate ";
$subject     = "42 Days Across Border Requirements";
$mainMessage = "Kindly Find the Attached File";
$fileatt     = "42dc-form.pdf";
$fileatttype = "application/pdf";
$fileattname = "42DaysAcrossBorders.pdf";
$headers     = 'From: info@travelmate.com.pk' . "\r\n" .
               'Reply-To: info@travelmate.com.pk' . "\r\n" .
               'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
// File
$file = fopen($fileatt, 'rb');
$data = fread($file, filesize($fileatt));
fclose($file);

// This attaches the file
$semi_rand     = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers      .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
                 "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
                 " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
$message       = "42 Days Across Borders Form.\n" .
                 "-{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                 "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\n" .
                 "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n" . $mainMessage  . "\n";

$data     = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
            "Content-Type: {$fileatttype};\n" .
            " name=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
            "filename=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n" .
            $data . "\n\n" .
            "-{$mime_boundary}-\n";
//$message = "sdfsdfsdf ";

if (mail($to,$subject, $mainMessage.$message, $headers)) {
    header('Location:index.php?s=success');
    $result='<div class="alert alert-success col-sm-12">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
}
```

Comment: You should consider using a framework like SwiftMailer, that helps you concentrating on the business logic rather than the basics of e-mails

Comment: what is mainMessage and then what is mesasge?

Comment: i want to send a message with it .. but only file is attaching no message body is received. If i remove $message only message is sending ..

Comment: Your body MIME boundary delimiters are incorrect. See IETF RFC-1341 "MIME  (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions)" Section "7.2.1 Multipart: The common syntax" - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1341